# No suitable method found to override but there is an method to be overridden

Tags: c#, interface

I have created a simple interface with the below code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DesignPattern_FactoryPattern
{
   interface Shape
    {
       void drawshape();
    }
}
```

Then, I have created another class with the below code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DesignPattern_FactoryPattern
{
    class Square : Shape
    {
        public override void drawshape() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shape is Square");
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following error:

> No suitable method found to be override.

Could you please help me?

Comment: You don't use `override` when implementing an Interface.

Comment: you can specify the member as `Virtual` before overriding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have:

- an interface named `Shape`
- a class named `Square` that implements the `Shape` interface

In that case, you need to drop the word `override`. The `drawShape` method in your `Square` class is the implementation of the method defined in the interface.

Let's say you had a base class named `Shape` and you had the `Square` class inherits from `Shape`. That is a case where the `drawShape` method would `override` the method of the same name in the base class.

Comment: Good answer.  I would also add that `Shape` should be `IShape` to follow naming conventions for interfaces, and that `override` only applies to base methods marked as `virtual`.

Comment: @DStanley Nit pick: Not only virtual methods. `abstract` methods too :)